# How do I reference the Reboot Pending Property in Burn (WiX)

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.6, burn

How do I reference the RebootPending property in a [Burn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX#Burn) (WiX) bootstrapper?
I know the property name is RebootPending, which is actually referencing the  MsiSystemRebootPending property in Windows Installer.

I'm currently trying something like this:

```
<bal:Condition Message="There is a restart pending. Please restart your computer before  attempting to install !(loc.ProductName).">RebootPending = 0</bal:Condition>
```

But it's always true, even when Windows Update has just finished an update and needs to restart.

Is my syntax wrong? Should my condition have [RebootPending] instead?

Having been informed that the RebootPending property inside Burn may not correspond exactly to the property that Windows Installer uses, how else would I ensure that my application does not attempt to install when a reboot is pending?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Burn doesn't use MSI's MsiSystemRebootPending because it operates outside an installation transaction. So Burn uses [ISystemInformation::RebootRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386098%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead. There's no guarantee that MSI and ISystemInformation::RebootRequired have the same idea about whether a reboot is required, since MSI doesn't document what MsiSystemRebootPending reflects.

Comment: As it turns out ISystemInformation::RebootRequired and MSI's MsiSystemRebootPending does indeed return different results.

Comment: @Randolph : better late than never. [I have added a sample below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49743175/129130). Just in case someone else should need it. I was looking at some other reboot stuff and found this. And Manas: yes, I have noticed this as well and tried to work out some of the details - but the ways of Windows are mysterious. `PendingFileRenameOperations` sets `MsiSystemRebootPending` to 1, but does not affect `ISystemInformation.RebootRequired` for example. Arnson - master of succinctness :-) - it is a silly little script, but it does the job? (not familiar with this object model).

Answer (score 2):

For some general ideas see tool [WhyReboot](http://exodusdev.com/products/whyreboot). Here is what it does:

> Examines documented registry locations for post-reboot file copy/rename/delete operations.
>
> Examines documented registy locations for "Run Once" applications:
>   these will run once on the next reboot, and are probably used by an
>   installer to perform post-reboot file cleanup and other operations
>   such as registry manipulation.
>
> Examines Wininit.ini on Win9x/ME platforms for pending file
>   rename/delete operations.

Answer (score 2):

***ISystemInformation::RebootRequired***: Somebody asked for some sample code to call [ISystemInformation::RebootRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386098%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) mentioned in Arnson's answer.

Here is one blurb - not exactly great, but maybe give it a try:

```vb
Set autoupdate = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate")
autoupdate.Pause()
MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description

Set sys = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.SystemInfo")
MsgBox sys.RebootRequired

' autoupdate.Resume() ' Enable to resume AutoUpdate
Set sys = Nothing
Set autoupdate = Nothing
```

Maybe just use the latter part:

```vb
Set sys = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.SystemInfo")
MsgBox sys.RebootRequired
Set sys = Nothing
```

I am not really familiar with [the Windows Update Agent Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

---

***Reboots***: There are many registry locations that can be involved in triggering a reboot (warning). [Get-PendingReboot-Query](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-PendingReboot-Query-bdb79542). And [a similar PowerShell script](https://gist.github.com/altrive/5329377).

Here are some registry locations I have found that are involved in Windows rebooting (definitely not exhaustive):

- `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Updates : UpdateExeVolatile`
- `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager : PendingFileRenameOperations`
- `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer : InProgress`
- `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing :  RebootPending`
- `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update : RebootRequired`
- `HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup : SystemSetupInProgress`

And computer rename operation in progress:

- `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ActiveComputerName : ComputerName`
- `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName : ComputerName`

[***CCMClientSDK***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj874138.aspx): And then there are some WMI calls to check for `SCCM 2012 Client Reboot Pending Status`. `CCMClientSDK.IsHardRebootPending` and `CCMClientSDK.RebootPending`. Check the [Get-PendingReboot-Query script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-PendingReboot-Query-bdb79542).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps but it says [here](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/bundle_built_in_variables.htm) that RebootPending value

> will reflect the reboot status of the system when the variable is first requested