# How can I detect an existing "currently suspended" install on the system?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn

I have a WiX Managed Bootstrapper Application (using a C#/WPF custom UI) that bundles several MSIs.  A user ran into a situation where the very first MSI to be installed after my MBA called the WiX base `BootstrapperApplication.Engine.Apply()` caused the `BootstrapperApplication.Error` event to fire with this information:

```
ErrorType: WindowsInstaller
ErrorCode: 1704 
ErrorMessage: An installation for Intel(R) Smart Connect Technology is currently suspended.  You must undo the changes made by that installation to continue.  Do you want to undo those changes?
```

Instead of handling this error when it occurs, I'd prefer to check if this condition (a "currently suspended" install of another MSI) exists on the machine and prevent the user from starting my installer's Apply action.

**How can I detect an existing "currently suspended" install on the system, preferably using the WiX DTF libraries?**

---

**Update:** Marking [Christopher Painter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21640204/682840), even though I'm unable to find any documentation to support it and am unable to reproduce the scenario myself.  I also found this question ["WIX Detect Pending Reboot"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283400/wix-detect-pending-reboot) which could also be related, but again has little useful official documentation.

Comment: Related post - [Roll back suspended .MSI install from command-line](https://serverfault.com/q/496109/329172)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need the DTF MSI interop. Just check for the following registry key:

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\InProgress

Comment: Is there any MSI documentation that explains this reg key? For example, can I determine what installer is suspended so I can tell the end user?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  There is a reference to it in he __MsiPromptForCD Mutex help topic but it's existence isn't defined anywhere else in the SDK.  My understanding is there will be an entry under that key pointing you to the suspended installation.  I'd have to test this on a VM to find out.